# Str in python for printing a List

Tags: python

Assume I have these classes:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x='A'):
        self.x = x

class ToPrint:
    def __init__(self, arg=1, grid=[]):
        self.arg = arg
        self.grid = grid

        self.grid = [Test, Test, Test]

    def __str__(self):
        row1 = self.grid[0].__str__() 

        return row1
```

I want to print the grid content:
`print(ToPrint.grid)`

In the above exemple, desired result should be : `A`

but I was unable to find the correct way to do that ? I have output like `<class '__main__.Test'>` or some errors.

Can you please give me some advice ?

Please note the `grid` is a list of `Test` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follows would achieve what you need:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x='A'):
        self.x = x
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.x

class ToPrint:
    def __init__(self, arg=1, grid=[Test(), Test(), Test()]):
        self.arg = arg
        self.grid = grid

    def __str__(self):
        row1 = str(self.grid[0])
        return row1

print(ToPrint())
```

So:

- you need to add a `__str__` definition for `Test`
- you need to pass instances of `Test` - `Test()` as default argument.

Comment: Thank's for your quick answer. I was to much focus on the "ToPrint" class :) Marked as solved